# Get values of foreign keys tables linked in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a question about foreign keys in a database. I am programming in c#, using the `Entity framework` (visual studio winforms) and I have data in my sql database with foreign keys.

I have queries which access these data to get them in a `Datagrid`. Everything is OK, except I have data in tables which are foreign keys (numbers). When I select them with queries I only get the foreign key (a number) and not the value which is linked in another table.

```
var requete_reservations = from reservation_spa in bdd.reservation_spa
                           where reservation_spa.NOMBRE_RESERVATION > 0
                           select new
                           {
                              reservation_spa.CLIENT,
                              reservation_spa.SPA,
                              reservation_spa.NOMBRE_RESERVATION                                            
                           };
dataGrid_reservations.DataSource = requete_reservations.ToList();
```

In `reservation_spa.client` I have a number which links another table client

[image: reservation_spa Table]

[image: Client table with linked key]

How can I get the **Name** from client using the foreign keys in `reservation_spa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Join table `reservation_spa` and `Client` like this :

```
var requete_reservations = from r in bdd.reservation_spa
                           join c in bdd.client on r.CLIENT equals c.IDCLIENT
                            where r.NOMBRE_RESERVATION > 0
                            select new
                            {
                                   c.NOM,
                                   r.SPA,
                                   r.NOMBRE_RESERVATION 
                            };
```

Comment: Yes! This solved my problem. Thank you for your explaination.

Comment: Glad to heart it! Thank you too :)

Comment: is it possible to join 2 tables in the same query? I have another table "spa" i have to join to "reservation_spa" to get the foreign key in "reservation_spa" which communicates with 2 tables (client and **spa** ) I have tried this but does not work

`var requete_reservations = from r in bdd.reservation_spa   
                                         from s in bdd.spa
                                           join c in bdd.client on r.CLIENT equals c.IDCLIENT
                                           join d in bdd.client on s.SERVICE equals d.IDCLIENT`

Comment: Yes you can, but like this : `from r in bdd.reservation_spa
join c in bdd.client on r.CLIENT equals c.IDCLIENT
join s in bdd.spa on r.SPA equals s.IDSPA `

Answer (score 0):

Where is the name for? If you just need the name you could use linq

```
var name= from c in bdd.Clients //Is that the name of the table of clients?
          where c.IDClient= requete_reservations.Client
          select c;
```